# Why is this dropdown not populating?

Tags: vb.net, html-select

I have three dropdowns; the second one (Members) populates based on what's in the first (Units), and the third one (Customers) SHOULD populate based on what's in the second; but it doesn't.

Here's the query that works in LINQPad (returns a list of Company names):

```
select distinct companyname from customers C left join members M on M.MemberNo = C.MemberNo where M.MemberNo = '052' order by companyname
```

...but does not work in the following code:

```
'Populate the Members dropdown
Dim selectedUnit As String = DropDownListUnits.Text
Dim membersDT As DataTable
sql = "select distinct shortname, M.memberno from members M left join memberunitproducts mup on M.MemberNo = mup.MemberNo where unit = '" + selectedUnit  + "' order by shortname"
retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
membersDT = retDS.Tables(0)
DropDownListMembers.DataSource = membersDT
DropDownListMembers.DataTextField = "shortname"
DropDownListMembers.DataValueField = "memberno"
DropDownListMembers.DataBind()

'Populate the Customers dropdown
Dim selectedMember As String = DropDownListMembers.DataValueField
Dim customersDT As DataTable
sql = "select distinct companyname from customers C left join members M on M.MemberNo = C.MemberNo where M.MemberNo = '" + selectedMember  + "' order by companyname"
retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
customersDT = retDS.Tables(0)
DropDownListCustomers.DataSource = customersDT
DropDownListCustomers.DataTextField = "companyname"
DropDownListCustomers.DataValueField = "companyname"
DropDownListCustomers.DataBind()
```

The third (Customers) dropdown remains unpopulated when this runs - why?

It's probably not needed, but here is the code for the first ("Units") dropdown:

```
'Populate the Units dropdown
Dim unitsDT As DataTable
sql = "Select distinct unit from masterunits where abs(active) = 1"
retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
unitsDT = retDS.Tables(0)
DropDownListUnits.DataSource = unitsDT
DropDownListUnits.DataTextField = "unit"
DropDownListUnits.DataValueField = "unit"
DropDownListUnits.DataBind()
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had to change this:

```
Dim selectedMember As String = DropDownListMembers.DataValueField
```

...to this:

```
Dim selectedMember As String = DropDownListMembers.SelectedItem.Value
```